# Effect not working in ajax call

Tags: ajax

I have this code in my ajax:

```
    $.ajax({    
url : "<?php echo site_url('user/add'); ?>",
                            type : 'POST',
                            data : form_data,
                            success : function(msg) {
                                $('#bid-form-part').html(msg).effect("pulsate", { times:3 }, 2000);
                                }
                        });
```

It shows the html I have send via ajax. thats fine, but the effect pulsate is not working at all ;)

Any suggestion what am I doing wrong?

I want that the new content blink once or a few times, but he code must be wrong or something.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Jquery API, there isn't a function called effect, try replacing it with a few fade outs and fade ins to see if they work instead?

e.g.

```
 $('#bid-form-part').html(msg).fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200).fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200).fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200);
```

its a bit long winded, but it allows you to see if it is going to work!

I would  have used a comment, but apparently my rep isn't high enough :D

Comment: thanks, this is working, however it moves my website up and down like I am moving a scrollbar with my mouse.

Comment: thought it would, before you start the fades (which effectively switch between display:none and display:block in css) try fixing the height of the container that #bid-form-part is in by getting the height of the parent and setting it with the height() function, that way, it wont shift when its faded, if that makes sense :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but maybe you are applying the pulsate method on the wrong element.
Try this instead:

```
$('#bid-form-part').html(msg);  
$('#bid-form-part').effect("pulsate", { times:3 }, 2000);
```

or choose another selector (some div inside the inserted)

Comment: to me it looks like after html(msg) it stops executing anything else. msg is just a simple html basically a div with a thank you message

Comment: try to put alert("test"); after html(msg). Something happens?

Comment: yes, but effect("pulsate", { times:3 }, 2000); do nothing at all.

Comment: yes, I have, but it is not working. I have also loaded in my header this library effect.core and effects.pulsate but nothing helps ;(

Comment: alert(jQuery.ui.version); shows jQuery 1.1.8.18 in a pop up. but if I try to add $('#d').effect("pulsate", { times:3 }, 2000);​ as you have done in jsfiddle nothing happens. I have added CSS and it is a red square and also the div is <div id="d">test</div>​, but it is not fadeng in and out like in jsfiddle ;(